# Can't Set Target Android version to Automatic

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have been following [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview) to implement a hybrid webview and am running into an issue with the Target Android version.  It states in the document:

> On Android Oreo ensure that the Android manifest sets the Target
>   Android version to Automatic. Otherwise, running this code will result
>   in the error message "invokeCSharpAction is not defined".

I am using the Android 8.1 - API 27 simulator and I am getting that error.  I tried to set the Target Android version to "Automatic" as it suggests in the Android Manifest portion of the project properties, but "Automatic" is not an option I can pick.  The only option I get that isn't a specific version is "Use Compile using SDK Version" and that doesn't solve the problem.  What am I missing?

Comment: Just set your Target Android Version to the same version as your Target Framework Version.

Comment: @JonDouglas I tried that with no luck.  I don't know if the problem is this version thing or possibly something else.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the following thread?

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/issues/343

It states that sample from the documentation does not work and needs to be changed according to the one posted in this thread. Please let me know if it helps or not.